# EF6 DbContext MySQL Table 'meconnec_db2.MEC_TBL_USER' doesn't exist

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

table name is mec_tbl_user in 'meconnec_db2' database.

[image: MEC_TBL_USER]

```
    public class MECContext : DbContext
    {
        public MECContext() : base("MECContext") 
        { 
        }

        public MECContext(string connstringName) : base(connstringName) { }

        public DbSet<MEC_TBL_USER> MEC_TBL_USER { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MEC_TBL_USER>().ToTable("MEC_TBL_USER");
        }
}

An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MECONNEC.Data.SQL.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Additional information: `Table 'meconnec_db2.MEC_TBL_USER' doesn't exist`

Comment: Is it case sensitive? Where are you defining your schema?

Comment: @Robbie Thanks it case sensitive solve this problem